# Shoutem Extension Settings

Tags: shoutem

I tried to write a settings page for my shoutem extension. I followed the following [tutorial](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/tutorials/writing-settings-page) and could get a working example using `Shortcut Settings`.

1. How do I implement `Extension Settings` using the `setttingsPage` tag in the `extension.json` file? Unfortunately I could not find any tutorial for that.
2. How do I access those extension setting values in my own extension (e.g. inside app.js)? I was able to access them in my own screen with:

   `const { shortcut } = this.props;
   const { greeting } = shortcut.settings;`

   But how do I do it inside app.js for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `settingsPages` in the root of `extensions.json`. The example you can find in our [Shopify extensions](https://github.com/shoutem/extensions/blob/master/shoutem-shopify/extension.json) and here's the [reference for extension.json](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/reference/extension).
2. To get extension settings, use `getExtensionSettings` selector. The example you can find in the [app/app.js](https://github.com/shoutem/extensions/blob/3a20ae8ce42bc1988ede5299a584ff49886e9a6c/shoutem-shopify/app/app.js#L1) of our Shopify extension.